# How is the set of functions on an open subset of a prevariety be seen as a $k$-subalgebra of the function field?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading Gortz&Wedhorn's *Algebraic Geometry I* and in Proposition 1.54 it asserts that for $U$ a non-empty open subset of a prevariety $X$, the set of functions on $U$, $\mathcal{O}_X(U) $, is a $k$-subalgebra of the function field $K(X)$, which is just defined in the same page in Definition 1.52 as the function field of nonempty open affine subvarities of $X$. In the proof of Proposition 1.54 there is no explaination for this statement.

Since there might not be a single open affine subvariety that contains $U$, I'm really confused about how the inclusion $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\subset K(X)$ is given (and in which way can this inclusion be canonical). Without understanding this, I cannot even understand what does the intersection $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\cap\mathcal{O}_X(V) $ really mean. This really stumped me.

The content of the book is as in the graphic below. Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fellows of mine just answered my question, so I'm writing this answer to close this question.

Since prevariety is irreducible, being both connected and a union of finite many irreducible spaces, any two (non-empty) open sets in the prevariety intersect. Therefore $U$ intersect $U_i$ for any open affine subvariety $U_i$. The proof of Proposition 1.54 tells that we have via the restriction map the inclusion $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\subset \mathcal{O}_X(U\cap U_i)\subset K(U_i)=K(X)$. This inclusion is well-defined, being independent of choice of $U_i$, since the restriction map gives commutative diagram

[image]

where the arrows are all inclusion.